# How to show picture in docker

Tags: python, docker, ssh, pytorch

my pycharm connect to a docker python interpreter.
if i run this code in pycharm

```
import os

import gym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython import display

os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'

env = gym.make('LunarLander-v2')
env.reset()

img = plt.imshow(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))

done = False
while not done:
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    observation, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
    img.set_data(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))
    display.display(plt.gcf())
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
```

i get

```
ssh://root@localhost:3999/opt/conda/bin/python -u /tmp/pycharm_project_399/test.py
Figure(640x480)
Figure(640x480)
Figure(640x480)
Figure(640x480)
Figure(640x480)
Figure(640x480)
Figure(640x480)
Figure(640x480)
Figure(640x480)
Figure(640x480)
Figure(640x480)
Figure(640x480)
Figure(640x480)
Figure(640x480)
```

I think the problem might be `display.display(plt.gcf())`.
because if i run `plt.show()` ,i can get a real picture.

If i don't change my code, what can i do to display the picture

Comment: Getting GUI applications to run in Docker is, at best, tricky and non-portable.  Use a host-based Python instead.

Comment: try `DISPLAY=":0" /opt/conda/bin/python ...`